# In App Purchase product screen doesn't populate for Apple Review Team, but DOES populate in my simulators and physical device in test

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, in-app-purchase

My iOS app was rejected by Apple, with the reason being they couldn't get my In-App Purchase to work. To start the IAP, I have buttons for the user to click, and the review team said when they tapped the buttons:

> they were unresponsive and the in-app purchase product payment screen did not populate.

This is very confusing as I've tested it in multiple simulators, as well as my physical iPad — the payment screen populates every time, and I'm able to complete the test transaction and complete the IAP.

I've been searching for what the issue may be and it's especially difficult when I can't actually replicate the issue myself. I can only think of a couple of possibilities, I'd appreciate if anyone can offer any advice / confirm or rule them out:

- I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aN-WWJA4TgM&list=LL&index=3&t=10s&ab_channel=R%26DLabswithRohant) when setting up my IAP. When following it I set up a Configuration.storekit file — should I have set my StoreKit Configuration back to "None" before submitting to Apple?
- In another tutorial, they said to add "In-App Purchase" on the Signing & Capabilities page (see screenshot). I hadn't done this before I submitted, might this be why the review team couldn't get it to work?

Are there any other reasons why they might not be able to use my IAP?

[image]

Comment: To your bullet points: Yes and yes. And test from a TestFlight build before submitting to Apple; running from Xcode is not a real test of what everyone else will see. Sounds like your submission to the Store was way premature.

Comment: Thanks, @matt. I'll make those adjustments and check out TestFlight. Maybe it was premature, but the app itself had been thoroughly tested, and the IAP seemed to be working without issues on my end, so I thought all was fine. It was the only issue Apple mentioned.

Comment: Or at the very least make yourself an Ad Hoc build. The point is that running from Xcode is not the same as running the app in the wild. No QA tester in the world runs the app from Xcode.